# How to uninstall Intel C++ from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-c++, intel

I just updated Intel C++ from 12.0 to 12.1. I uninstalled the 12.0 from the control Panel, but I notice it is still available in the Visual Studio 2010 platform toolset (in addition to Intel C++ 12.1). How to remove the entry? I'd appreciate if someone could help.

> Blockquote
>   C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\Intel C++ Compiler XE 12.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Intel C++ Compiler XE 12.0.targets(43,5): error : Could not expand ICInstallDir variable.  PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number.
>   Blockquote

Version 12.0 certainly isn't available any more judging from what I'm getting in the output log

Edit: Is it safe to just delete the Intel C++ Compiler XE 12.0 folders from C:\Program Files\MSBuild..\ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uninstall Intel's add-in to VS, not only Intel compiler and libraries.

Comment: Yes I know that, but how to do it?

Comment: I did, there is no Intel C++ entry there. But the following step did the trick.
I deleted the Intel C++ Compiler XE 12.0 folders in C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\ and C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\

Comment: Well, the problem solved, congratulations. My guess is that VS was open when you uninstalled Intel, so some file handles were locked and files stayed on your machine.

Comment: Yes, could be. I recall I didn't close all open applications while uninstalling.